# Power function runtime error

Tags: mingw

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main(void)
{
  int x,y,g,f,r,X=0,Y=0;
  double res=0;
  printf("\nEnter the x and y coordinate of the point separated by a space");
  scanf("%d %d",&x,&y);
  printf("\nEnter the coordinates of the center of the circle ");
  scanf("%d %d",&g,&f);
  printf("\nEnter the radius of the circle");
  scanf("%d",r);
  X=x-g;
  Y=y-f;
  res=(pow((double)X,2.0)+pow((double)Y,2.0)-pow((double)r,2.0));
  printf("%lf",res);
  if(res>0)
    printf("\nThe point lies inside the circle");
  else if(!res)
    printf("\nThe point lies on the circle ");
  else if(res>0)
    printf("\nThe point lies outside the circle");
    getch();
  return 0;
}
```

The above code is a program to check whether a point lies inside a circle or not (and I was specifically asked to use the power function of C). I am using MinGW (the latest version as of 6/14/2013) to compile my program, Windows 7 OS.

The program compiles without any errors or warnings.

However, when I run it in the command prompt, the program abruptly terminates once I've entered all the details. Since the next step is the calculation of `res`, I figured there is an error with the usage of the power function. Please point out the relevant mistakes.

Comment: What does the debugger say?

Comment: offtopic but I know you were specifically asked to use pow but don't use `pow((double)X,2.0)` when you can simply write `(double)X*X` (for next times).

Comment: sorry,i overlooked the obvious while in haste,(ROOKIE HERE) but the question cannot be deleted now i guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the program compiles without any errors or warnings

***FAKE***

You don't compile with `-Wall`, do you?

```
quirk.c:12:11: warning: format specifies type 'int *' but the argument has type 'int' [-Wformat]
  scanf("%d",r);
         ~^  ~
quirk.c:12:14: warning: variable 'r' is uninitialized when used here [-Wuninitialized]
  scanf("%d",r);
             ^
quirk.c:5:16: note: initialize the variable 'r' to silence this warning
  int x,y,g,f,r,X=0,Y=0;
               ^
                = 0
```

C is still a pass-by-value-only language. In order `scanf()` to be able to modify its argument, you need to pass a pointer to the variable. But instead of a valid pointer, you pass in an uninitialized integer, which it then tries to dereference as a pointer and **Boom!** There goes a segfault.

Change

```
scanf("%d",r);
```

to

```
scanf("%d", &r);
```

(And insert some vertical space, it would make your program readable.)

Answer (score 2):

`scanf("%d",r);` should be `scanf("%d", &r);`

Always compile with warnings, my compiler immediately pointed out the problem:

`warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat]`